# Pop to rootviewcontroller when tabbarcontroller is dismissed?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I have login screen (viewcontroller) and then another signature screen (viewcontroller). Then tabbar controller is presented above signature screen. when the user tap logout button in tabbar controller stack the app should navigate to login screen. I have tried dismissing tabbar controller, but it is not navigating to login screen instead it is navigating to signature screen.

Below is the navigation structure

UINavigationController -- ViewController1 (Login Screen)
                           | 
                            --- ViewController2 (Signature Screen)
                               |
                               --- TabbarController (Five Tab Items)

How can i navigate to login screen. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is pushed into a nav controller and what is presented (modal)?

Comment: I have pushed two view controllers (login and signature screens) and tabbar controller is presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the signature view controller presents the tab controller, do this:

```
[self presentViewController:tabController
                   animated:YES
                 completion:^{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}];
```

Then, when the tab controller is dismissed the login view will already be there waiting.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
[navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```